# Как получить value всех input-ов?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Мне нужно получить значение всех инпутов, каждый из которых находится в родительском блоке. И полученные значения, сложить в сумме.

```
    <div class="total">
         <input class="hidden-grand-total" value="130">
    </div>
<div class="total">
         <input class="hidden-grand-total" value="0">
    </div>
<div class="total">
         <input class="hidden-grand-total" value="80">
    </div>
```

Я пытаюсь сделать это примерно так:

```
$('.total').find('.hidden-grand-total').each(function(i) {
      console.log($('.total').find('.hidden-grand-total').val());
});
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```js
let id = $('.total').map(function(i, el) {
  return $('.hidden-grand-total', el).val();
}).get();
console.log(id);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="total">
  <input class="hidden-grand-total" value="130">
</div>
<div class="total">
  <input class="hidden-grand-total" value="0">
</div>
<div class="total">
  <input class="hidden-grand-total" value="80">
</div>
```

**UPD** Не заметил сразу, что нужна сумма значений. Исправляюсь:

```js
let sum = $('.total').get().reduce(function(p, c) {
  return +$('.hidden-grand-total', c).val() + p;
}, 0);
console.log(sum);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="total">
  <input class="hidden-grand-total" value="130">
</div>
<div class="total">
  <input class="hidden-grand-total" value="0">
</div>
<div class="total">
  <input class="hidden-grand-total" value="80">
</div>
```

Comment: "И полученные значения, сложить в сумме."

Comment: @Anamnian, да, прошло мимо моих глаз )) Дополнил вариантом ответ

Answer (score 4):

Сделал вариант с суммированием значений.

```js
var sum = 0;

$('.total').find('.hidden-grand-total').each(function() {
      sum = sum + parseInt($(this).val());
});

console.log(sum);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="total">
         <input class="hidden-grand-total" value="130">
    </div>
<div class="total">
         <input class="hidden-grand-total" value="0">
    </div>
<div class="total">
         <input class="hidden-grand-total" value="80">
    </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
var inputGrand = document.querySelectorAll('.hidden-grand-total');
var inputGrandSum = 0;

for(var i = 0; i < inputGrand.length; i++){ 
 inputGrandSum += parseFloat(inputGrand[i].value); 
}
console.log(inputGrandSum);
document.querySelector('.result').innerHTML = 'Сумма ' +  inputGrandSum;
```

```html
<div class="total">
    <input class="hidden-grand-total" value="130">
</div>
<div class="total">
    <input class="hidden-grand-total" value="0">
</div>
<div class="total">
    <input class="hidden-grand-total" value="80">
</div>

<div class="result"></div>
```